# What is the easiest way to clean up messy rowdata dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a messy dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('Chicken','Chicken1','ChiCKen','Chicke_N',
                      'Eg_g','EGG','egg'))

levels(as.factor(df$name))

[1] "Chicke_N" "Chicken"  "ChiCKen"  "Chicken1" "Eg_g"     "egg"      "EGG"
```

What would be the most efficient way of cleaning up these names, making them either `'chicken'` or `'egg'`?

I thought something like this would work:

```
df <- df%>% mutate(name = ifelse(name %in% c('Chicken','Chicken1','ChiCKen','Chicke_N'),'chicken','egg'))
```

I was wrong.

Comment: `ifelse(grepl('chicken', df$name, ignore.case = TRUE), 'chicken', 'egg')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changes to lower case and removes all punctuation and (contiguous) numbers, so it works on the given examples.

```
data.frame(name = c('Chicken','Chicken1','ChiCKen','Chicke_N',
                    'Eg_g','EGG','egg')) %>% 
  mutate(name = tolower(name) %>% stringr::str_remove("[[:punct:]]|\\d+"))
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if I want to map something like `'bird'` to chicken?

Comment: You might consider a lookup table with those translations. Then you could join to that table and use if_else() or coalesce() to select the replacement where available.

Answer (score 1):

For a versatile approach, you might consider joining by `stringdistance`.
Make sure to read the helpfiles on the different methods for computing stringdistance (i.e. osa, lv, dl, hamming, lcs, qgram, cosine, jaccard, jw and soundex).

```
df.valid <- data.frame(name = c("chicken", "egg"))

library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df %>% stringdist_left_join(df.valid, ignore_case = TRUE, max_dist = 5)

#     name.x  name.y
# 1  Chicken chicken
# 2 Chicken1 chicken
# 3  ChiCKen chicken
# 4 Chicke_N chicken
# 5     Eg_g     egg
# 6      EGG     egg
# 7      egg     egg
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use *approximate* matching by using `agrepl`.

```
df |> 
 mutate(cleaned = ifelse(agrepl("chicken", df$name, ignore.case = TRUE), "chicken", "egg"))

      name cleaned
1  Chicken chicken
2 Chicken1 chicken
3  ChiCKen chicken
4 Chicke_N chicken
5     Eg_g     egg
6      EGG     egg
7      egg     egg
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use lookup tables:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('Chicken','Chicken1','ChiCKen','Chicke_N',
                      'Eg_g','EGG','egg'))

lkup <- data.frame(name = levels(as.factor(df$name)),
                   clean = c('chicken','chicken','chicken','chicken',
                             'egg','egg','egg'))
inner_join(df,lkup,by='name') %>% mutate(name = clean) %>% select(name)
```

This method is more verbose, but in some cases the name might not be coercible, for example when trying to match `'bird'` to chicken..